# How to check for duplicate email address in spartacus storefront?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

How can you check that an email address already exists in Spartacus? The reference class for this type of query would be `UserService`. But it does not contain this kind of method or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, we had this functionality built in. But because of security reasons our backend is not sending us any feedback about email/password/account being incorrect/existing/etc anymore. So even if you'd do anything on the frontend, the backend will not help with that.

Here's one of the PRs, where we had to [change the register flow](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/3989) - before, it was logging you in automatically once registered successfully, but if your email was already used, it wasn't logging you in - boom, security issue (possibility to check if a given email is used on this specific site)

So, unless you customize your backend (not sure if even possible), you cannot really check if email already exists in Spartacus.

Comment: @Kackper Knapik What if you use something like `this._userConnector.get(userId).subscribe(() => {`  and in the block of subscribe you do the handling that you would normally do in the true branch of an `if` when the user exists? But this triggers that red ribbon in case of error, so this might be troublesome in case you want to treat the errors is a different way.

Comment: @Kackper Knapik Also, on which files in that pull request were you referring?

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/3989/files#diff-e6d100f0042d99aa830e4c11acc9ee55R92 <- here you can see logging in automatically if you registered successfully (security issue) - already removed, and here: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/3989/files#diff-e6d100f0042d99aa830e4c11acc9ee55R157 <- you have the current solution, which is redirecting to login page